# Can't uncheck inputs

Tags: pine-script

I am working on a indicator which shows the aggregated trading volume of multiple BTC markets.

The indicator works for the most part but for some reason unchecking inputs does not work.
Even when everything is unchecked the indicator still plots the aggregated volume of all markets.

It is probably a simple fix but I have no background in coding. I got to this point by looking at other indicators and a bit of trial and error.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

I am also thinking it would be very interesting to be able to see what volume came from every single market by plotting the histogram in multiple colors, but I do not think I can pull that off  or if it is even possible.

This is the entire code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Aggregated Bitcoin Volume", overlay=false)


sym1_title  = "Binance (USDT)"
sym1_ticker = "BINANCE:BTCUSDT"
sym2_title  = "Binance (BUSD)"
sym2_ticker = "BINANCE:BTCBUSD"
sym3_title  = "Bitfinex (USD)"
sym3_ticker = "BITFINEX:BTCUSD"
sym4_title  = "Coinbase (USD)"
sym4_ticker = "COINBASE:BTCUSD"
sym5_title  = "Coinbase (USDC)"
sym5_ticker = "COINBASE:BTCUSDC"
sym6_title  = "Bitstamp (USD)"
sym6_ticker = "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD"
sym7_title  = "Kraken (USD)"
sym7_ticker = "KRAKEN:XBTUSD"
sym8_title  = "Gemini (USD)"
sym8_ticker = "GEMINI:BTCUSD"
sym9_title  = "OkEx (USDT)"
sym9_ticker = "OKEX:BTCUSDT"
sym10_title  = "OkEx (USDK)"
sym10_ticker = "OKEX:BTCUSDK"
sym11_title  = "Huobi (USDT)"
sym11_ticker = "HUOBI:BTCUSDT"

sym1 = input(title=sym1_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym2 = input(title=sym2_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym3 = input(title=sym3_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym4 = input(title=sym4_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym5 = input(title=sym5_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym6 = input(title=sym6_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym7 = input(title=sym7_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym8 = input(title=sym8_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym9 = input(title=sym9_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym10 = input(title=sym10_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)
sym11 = input(title=sym11_title, type=input.bool, defval=true)

src = input(close)

price_1 = security(sym1_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_2 = security(sym2_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_3 = security(sym3_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_4 = security(sym4_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_5 = security(sym5_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_6 = security(sym6_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_7 = security(sym7_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_8 = security(sym8_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_9 = security(sym9_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_10 = security(sym10_ticker, timeframe.period, src)
price_11 = security(sym11_ticker, timeframe.period, src)

security_1 = security(sym1_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_2 = security(sym2_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_3 = security(sym3_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_4 = security(sym4_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_5 = security(sym5_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_6 = security(sym6_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_7 = security(sym7_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_8 = security(sym8_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_9 = security(sym9_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_10 = security(sym10_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)
security_11 = security(sym11_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)


plot(series=(security_1+security_2+security_3+security_4+security_5+security_6+security_7+security_8+security_9+security_10+security_11), style=plot.style_histogram, color = #787b86, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Aggregated Bitcoin Volume", overlay=false)

sym1        = input(true, "", input.bool, inline="1")
sym2        = input(true, "", input.bool, inline="2")
sym3        = input(true, "", input.bool, inline="3")

sym1_ticker = input("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", "", input.symbol, inline="1")
sym2_ticker = input("BINANCE:BTCBUSD", "", input.symbol, inline="2")
sym3_ticker = input("BITFINEX:BTCUSD", "", input.symbol, inline="3")

f_volume(_ticker) => security(_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)

volume_1 = sym1 ? f_volume(sym1_ticker) : 0
volume_2 = sym2 ? f_volume(sym2_ticker) : 0
volume_3 = sym3 ? f_volume(sym3_ticker) : 0

volume_agg = volume_1 + volume_2 + volume_3

plot(volume_agg, style=plot.style_columns, color = #787b86)
```

Plotting the histogram in multiple stacked colors is not possible in Pine.

**Edit 1**
It seems there's a way after all to plot the histogram in multiple stacked colors.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Aggregated Volume", precision=0, overlay=false)

// Plot style selections
var string PS1 = "Columns"
var string PS2 = "Histogram"

// Inputs
i_sym1          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="1")
i_sym2          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="2")
i_sym3          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="3")
i_sym4          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="4")
i_sym5          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="5")
i_sym6          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="6")
i_sym7          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="7")
i_sym8          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="8")
i_sym9          = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="9")
i_sym10         = input(true,              "", input.bool,   inline="10")

i_sym1_color    = input(color.red,         "", input.color,  inline="1")
i_sym2_color    = input(color.orange,      "", input.color,  inline="2")
i_sym3_color    = input(color.yellow,      "", input.color,  inline="3")
i_sym4_color    = input(color.green,       "", input.color,  inline="4")
i_sym5_color    = input(color.blue,        "", input.color,  inline="5")
i_sym6_color    = input(color.purple,      "", input.color,  inline="6")
i_sym7_color    = input(color.teal,        "", input.color,  inline="7")
i_sym8_color    = input(color.gray,        "", input.color,  inline="8")
i_sym9_color    = input(color.lime,        "", input.color,  inline="9")
i_sym10_color   = input(color.fuchsia,     "", input.color,  inline="10")

i_sym1_ticker   = input("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", "", input.symbol, inline="1")
i_sym2_ticker   = input("BINANCE:BTCBUSD", "", input.symbol, inline="2")
i_sym3_ticker   = input("BITFINEX:BTCUSD", "", input.symbol, inline="3")
i_sym4_ticker   = input("COINBASE:BTCUSD", "", input.symbol, inline="4")
i_sym5_ticker   = input("BINGBON:BTCUSDT", "", input.symbol, inline="5")
i_sym6_ticker   = input("BITSTAMP:BTCUSD", "", input.symbol, inline="6")
i_sym7_ticker   = input("KRAKEN:XBTUSD",   "", input.symbol, inline="7")
i_sym8_ticker   = input("GEMINI:BTCUSD",   "", input.symbol, inline="8")
i_sym9_ticker   = input("OKEX:BTCUSDT",    "", input.symbol, inline="9")
i_sym10_ticker  = input("HUOBI:BTCUSDT",   "", input.symbol, inline="10")

i_plot_style    = input(PS1,        "Plot style",       input.string, options=[PS1,PS2])

i_single_color  = input(false,      "Use single color", input.bool,   inline="0")
i_default_color = input(color.gray, "",                 input.color,  inline="0")

// Variables
var int   plot_style   = i_plot_style == PS1 ? plot.style_columns : plot.style_histogram
var color sym1_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym1_color
var color sym2_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym2_color
var color sym3_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym3_color
var color sym4_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym4_color
var color sym5_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym5_color
var color sym6_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym6_color
var color sym7_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym7_color
var color sym8_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym8_color
var color sym9_color   = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym9_color
var color sym10_color  = i_single_color ? i_default_color : i_sym10_color

// Functions
f_volume(_ticker) => security(_ticker, timeframe.period, volume)

// Calculations
v1  =       i_sym1  ? f_volume(i_sym1_ticker)  : 0
v2  = v1 + (i_sym2  ? f_volume(i_sym2_ticker)  : 0)
v3  = v2 + (i_sym3  ? f_volume(i_sym3_ticker)  : 0)
v4  = v3 + (i_sym4  ? f_volume(i_sym4_ticker)  : 0)
v5  = v4 + (i_sym5  ? f_volume(i_sym5_ticker)  : 0)
v6  = v5 + (i_sym6  ? f_volume(i_sym6_ticker)  : 0)
v7  = v6 + (i_sym7  ? f_volume(i_sym7_ticker)  : 0)
v8  = v7 + (i_sym8  ? f_volume(i_sym8_ticker)  : 0)
v9  = v8 + (i_sym9  ? f_volume(i_sym9_ticker)  : 0)
v10 = v9 + (i_sym10 ? f_volume(i_sym10_ticker) : 0)

if i_single_color
    v1 := na, v2 := na, v3 := na, v4 := na, v5 := na, v6 := na, v7 := na, v8 := na,  v9 := na

// Plots
plot(v10, style=plot_style, color=sym10_color, linewidth=1)
plot(v9 , style=plot_style, color=sym9_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v8 , style=plot_style, color=sym8_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v7 , style=plot_style, color=sym7_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v6 , style=plot_style, color=sym6_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v5 , style=plot_style, color=sym5_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v4 , style=plot_style, color=sym4_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v3 , style=plot_style, color=sym3_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v2 , style=plot_style, color=sym2_color,  linewidth=1)
plot(v1 , style=plot_style, color=sym1_color,  linewidth=1)
```

Which yields

[image: Example]

I've also added an option to choose the plot style and an option to show everything in one color.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

I have added a few lines so the the indicator aggregates data from more exchanges and it has been working great.

This indicator works so well I thought it would be nice to (with your consent) publish it on TradingView. The information it provides is pretty handy, and I think quite a few people would be happy to use it.

I have published an indicator before so I could publish it, with a note you wrote the code if you want that.

Vriendelijke groet vanuit Nederland,
Dennis

| Op uw profielpagina staat dat u uit Vlaanderen komt :)

Comment: Sure, no worries. Go for it. No need to mention me, although I'd appreciate it if you could add a link to it in the comments here, once it's published, so that I can have a look. And <dutch>inderdaad, we spreken beiden Nederlands :)</dutch> but  per SO rules, we'll keep it in English.

Comment: Link to the indicator: https://www.tradingview.com/script/ijEqnAel-Aggregated-Volume/

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer. You might like this one better :)

Comment: Wow, that's nothing short of awesome! Shortly after you posted your first answer, I found an indicator which is able to display the histograms in multiple colors. I tried to implement the part of your code with which you can change the entered markets on the input page, but I couldn't get it to work. I was thinking on whether I would ask you to help me again before going back to this page and seeing you had left a message a few minutes ago with great news. Thank you very much! <dutch> Heel erg bedankt! :) </dutch> If you are okay with it I'll publish this code as well and leave a link again.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Could you also post a link here to that indicator you found for the multi-color histograms? I'd like to see how others approached this problem.

Comment: This is the link to that other indicator: https://www.tradingview.com/script/wMbBUhUH/

Comment: Thanks. It's the same approach as I used apparently.

Comment: Link: https://www.tradingview.com/script/V3q0WkG6-Aggregated-Volume-Colored-Bitcoin-ETH-Altcoins-everything/